# ConfigMap Kubernetes YAML: space in value is causing error

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

For some strange and unknown reason, when I use a ConfigMap with key value pairs that will be set as environment variables in the pods (using `envFrom`), my pods fail to start.

Here is the ConfigMap portion of my YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: all-config
data:
  # DB configuration
  dbServer: "host.docker.internal"
  dbPort: "3306"

  # problematic config
  validationQuery: 'Select 1'
```

If I comment out the `validationQuery` key/value pair, the pod starts. If I leave it in, it fails. If I remove the space, it runs! Very strange behavior as it boils down to a whitespace.

Any ideas on why this fails and how users have been getting around this? Can someone try to reproduce?

Comment: What happens if you switch to double quotes?, like `"Select 1"`

Comment: are you getting any verbose errors you can share with us?

Comment: Double quotes did not work. It was an experiment to go to single quotes.

I am unable to get any logs from the instance.

Comment: @Hackerman As there are no characters that need escaping in that scalar, I am not aware of any parser (apart from my ruamel.yaml module in round-trip-mode) making a difference in loaded value between a single quoted scalar (`'Select 1'`),  a double quoted scalar (`"Select 1"`) and a plain scalar (`Select 1`). Can you elaborate on why you think changing to double quotes would make a difference? (The only quotes in the example that would make a difference, when removed, are those around `3306`)

Answer (score 3):

I honestly believe that it's something with your application not liking environment variables with spaces. I tried this myself and I can see the environment variable with the space nice and dandy when I shell into the pod/container.

PodSpec:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - /bin/sleep
    - infinity
    env:
    - name: WHATEVER
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          key: myenv
          name: j
...
```

---

```
$ kubectl get cm j -o=yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  myenv: Select 1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-10T20:44:02Z
  name: j
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "11111111"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/j
  uid: aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaa
```

---

```
root@mypod-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx:/# echo $WHATEVER
Select 1
root@mypod-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx:/#
```

Comment: Thanks for running that test! Sadly, I can assure the application is fine with that value because it works as an environment variable in a non k8's environment.